# Neovim nvim-jdtls Error Client 1 quit with exit code 13 and signal 0

Tags: neovim, lsp, filetype-java

i tried setting up my neovim with the nvim-jdtls plugin (https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls)
But I always get a `Client 1 quit with exit code 13 and signal 0` Error Message.

I followed the troubleshooting guide and tried to start the equinox launcher as follows:
`java -jar /Library/Java/jdt-language-server-latest/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar` and it produces an error-message:

```
!SESSION 2021-11-25 14:49:06.789 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=17.0.1
java.vendor=Homebrew

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-11-25 14:49:06.952
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
```

Maybe somebody knows where the error is?
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse) useful